# Gitlab multiple folders rule

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

Are there ways to merge row changes of multiple folders into a single row?

For instance,

```
 changes:
      - api/**/*
      - config/**/*
      - controllers/**/*
      - hack/**/*
      ... and etc 7 lines...
```

Combine to the 1 line? In short, I want to list all folders in the root directory by one line to avoid bulky part in changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reduce the lines, you can change the following syntax
From this

```
 changes:
      - api/**/*
      - config/**/*
      - controllers/**/*
      - hack/**/*
```

To

```
 changes:
      [api/**/*, config/**/*, controllers/**/*, hack/**/*]
```

Comment: But if i use this syntax it looks like i cant add something else in changes as a new line

Comment: @LordKnows Can you give an example? What else did you  try to add in the changes directive?

Comment: I already found a solution, I just want to add some files to this line. I did it with *.{files}. Thanks.